# Uiview animation doesn't work

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

So it is my code:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        if (!header) {
            header = [[CustomBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
            float number = [self.total floatValue];
            [self updateTotalLabel: &number];
        }
        return header;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)updateTotalLabel:(float *)amount
{
    float currentValue = [self.total floatValue];
    self.total = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(currentValue + *amount)];
    [header updateLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:TOTAL, [total floatValue]]];
}
```

header updateLabel:

```
-(void)updateLabel:(NSString *)string
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = frame;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
    self.frame = frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.label.text = string;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = frame;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];

    [label setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I am calling updateTotalLabel, every time when user adds new record to tableview. 
I have a problem with animation because, animation works only after first call updateLabel.

EDIT

Ok, so I rec a movie: [YT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsoBEmANfJk)

In output you can see when each animation is trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your problem is, as there is really no description of what is happening and what is not happening. I do see a problem with your animation code though. You're attempting to use delays to allow for multiple continuous animations. It might work, I really don't know. However, a better method is just to use the completion block to continue with what ever animation you want. Try this:

```
-(void)updateLabel:(NSString *)string
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = frame;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done 1!");
                         frame.origin.y = 0;
                         self.label.text = string;
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.frame = frame;
                                          } 
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              NSLog(@"Done 2!");
                                              [label setNeedsDisplay];
                                          }];
                     }];



}
```